# Gattermann-Koch Reaction with Phenol Substrates

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, phenols

The Gattermann-Koch Reaction involves the formation of an aryl aldehyde using carbon monoxide and hydrochloric acid as reactants. The reaction is catalyzed by aluminium trichloride in the presence of trace amounts of cuprous chloride.

[image]

What I don't understand about this reaction is that according to Wikipedia along with other online texts I've used, the Gattermann-Koch reaction is inapplicable to phenol substrates. The drawback has been left unexplained by *all* my resources (online and textbooks) and even my professor was oblivious to it.
I am unable to understand why the reaction doesn't apply to phenol and what exact side reactions might occur.

Additionally, why is the explanation so obscure?

[EDIT] I found the explanation. The Gattermann-Koch Reaction is not applicable to phenol and phenol ethers because they "could not be successfully formylated at atmospheric pressure in benzene as a solvent."
"This failure to react was attributed to the insolubility of the cuprous chloride in the reaction mixture."

Can someone please explain this in simple terms?

Comment: [This](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31531/friedel-crafts-reaction-of-phenol/31548#31548) question might be of interest to you as it is closely related.

Comment: You should try to consult it from books

Answer (score 8):

You have outlined that the **formyl chloride** is generated as the reactive, electrophilic intermediate under these conditions.

You are planning to perform an electrophilic aromatic substitution, but in a phenol, there's high electron density on the $\ce{O}$ atom. Isn't it conceivable that your main reaction product is phenylformate here, resulting from $\ce{O}$-acylation?

Comment: I didn't consider that, but then why would that only apply for phenol substrates? Wouldn't amines and ethers also be reactive in the same manner?

Comment: @tennispro1213 Primary and secondary amines will undergo N-acylation as well, Ethers, such as anisole, on the other hand, can be formylated in a Gattermann-Koch reaction.

Comment: can we simply say that the Gattermann-Koch Reaction is generally not used in compounds containing strongly basic groups?

Comment: @tennispro1213 We could say that the *Gattermann-Koch* or the *Vilsmeier-Haack* reaction can lead to heteroatom acylation. In the case of phenols, we'd use the *Reimer-Tiemann* or the *Duff* reaction instead.

Comment: How sure can we be that we actually have formyl chloride as a reactive intermediate? I could imagine to have only protonated carbonmonoxide, according to $$\ce{CO + HCl + AlCl3 <=> H+CO + [AlCl4]^-}$$. Also cuprous chloride seems to play an important role in the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Phenol can act as Lewis base and form adduct with AlCl3, using a lone pair on the O atom, hence deactivating the ring for further reaction.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favourite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect that, in the presence of the Lewis Acid catalyst, even if a formyl ester is formed, it will rearrange the the acylbenzene, which is irreversible. This may have consequences for the o,p-product ratio,
And as far as the cuprous chloride, use aluminum trichloride. And you could make the Scylla bromide first, with Formica acid an bromine. Much more reactive will likely form the sculpture ester first, in catalyze. Then catalyst to rearrange it

Comment: Are you simply trying to put obscure words in last sentences? I know what Scylla is and it's not some wacky mythology chemistry here...

Comment: I have to agree, this looks like an autocorrect nightmare.  Can you polish it up a bit?