# Why does phenol react on oxygen in the Gattermann–Koch reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, phenols, regioselectivity

When discussing the Gattermann–Koch reaction on phenol substrates, it [has been said](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31929/16683) that *O*-acylation is a problematic competing reaction as

> in a phenol, there's high electron density on the O atom [...]

However, there are also numerous other reactions where phenol reacts with electrophiles on the benzene ring. Some examples are:

- the [Houben–Hoesch synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoesch_reaction) (a kind of FC acylation);
- the [Riemer–Tiemann reaction](http://www.name-reaction.com/reimer-tiemann-reaction);
- the reaction of phenol with nitrous acid to form 4-nitrosophenol;
- the [Kolbe–Schmitt](http://www.name-reaction.com/kolbe-schmitt-reaction) reaction; and
- the [Vilsmeier reaction](http://www.name-reaction.com/vilsmeier-haack-reaction), amongst others.

Why is the Gatterman–Koch reaction an exception?

Comment: Can anyone please explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: There isn't really any literature evidence to support the fact that it *does* react @ oxygen (though it is quite probable). In the Gattermann-Koch mechanism, the intermediate is highly reactive, the Gattermann modification avoids this, making it amenable to synthesis (Gattermann conditions + phenol are fine and have been used in many syntheses).  The original Gatterman report of phenols not being amenable to G-K conditions is @ DOI: 10.1002/jlac.19073570209 (German language, very hard to decipher),  DOI:10.1002/0471264180.or009.02 also has an overview (English language).

Comment: @NotEvans. I've read the abstract of the English version which says that the Gattermann reaction with $\ce{CN}$ as a reagent reacts on benzene, but I am confused about the Gattermann koch version.

Comment: Here is your source:https://www.vedantu.com/chemistry/gattermann-koch-reaction