# Why does phenol not undergo Friedel-Crafts alkylation and acylation reactions, whereas anisole does?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[Friedel–Crafts reaction of phenol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31531/friedel-crafts-reaction-of-phenol)

The answer to the question at the above link states that : "Like aniline, phenol too reacts to a very less extent during Friedal-Crafts reaction.
The reason being that the oxygen atom of phenol has lone pair of electrons which coordinate with Lewis acid."

**But isn't the case with anisole, the same?** However, my textbook states that anisole does undergo Friedel-Crafts acylation and alkylation.

Comment: You and the textbook are both correct. Anisole does undergo FC reactions but the O can coordinate (more weakly than in the case of phenol),  leading to demethylation.  It all depends on your reaction conditions and Lewis acid.