# Why cannot nitrosonium ion attack aniline in electrophylic aromatic substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, amines

This is the nitrosonium ion, which is produced by the reaction of $\ce{NaNO2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$:

[image]

[**Image source: Wikipedia**]

And this is the reaction between aniline and nitrosonium:

[image]

[**Image source: Wikipedia**]

Cannot it take place as an EAS, and with substitution at the ortho or para positions? The amino group is a very good activating group for EAS after all.

**Update**: I forgot to mention that EAS is observed in case $\ce{-NR2}$ is attached to the ring in place of $\ce{-NH2}$.

Comment: You certainly could. If I had to offer a post hoc justification, it's probably that at 0 degrees, the rate of ring substitution is extremely slow and cannot compete with N-attack. There is a similar selectivity question in, for example, the acylation of phenol. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31531/friedel-crafts-reaction-of-phenol

Answer (score 5):

What actually happens is that the nitrosonium ion always adds faster to the amino nitrogen.  But that reaction is rapidly reversible unless a proton can dissociate from the amino nitrogen to give a stable N-nitroso product.

A primary or secondary amine has the required N-H proton, and in the case of a primary amine the presence of a second N-H proton enables further reaction making a diazonium ion (as shown for aniline by the OP) or even molecuar nitrogen.  But a tertiary amine has no N-H proton for the elimination step.  A tertiary amine then undergoes no net nitrosation reaction at the *nitrogen atom*, but if it's *aromatic* then EAS emerges as an alternative.