# Friedel-Crafts reaction of anisole?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

We know that phenol and aniline, despite being strongly activating, are unable to to undergo Friedel-Crafts reactions because they form complexes with $\ce{AlCl3}$, thanks to the lone pair on nitrogen and oxygen atoms.

However, according to my notes (and Google) anisole does undergo Friedel-Crafts reactions. How can it be possible, why is there no complex formation this time?

Also, I wanted to know how can we say that a certain group like $\ce{OH}$ will surely form a complex? Is containing a lone pair a sufficient condition?

Comment: What complex does it form?

Comment: @Yashas For eg, phenol forms Ar-(OH+)-(AlCl3-)

Comment: Not sure if this correct, but you could use alkyl triflate, instead of alkyl chloride + $\ce{AlCl3}$. Triflate is a good leaving group and can generate carbocations with easily react with the activated ring of phenol or aniline.

Comment: Completely a duplicate of **https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31531/friedel-crafts-reaction-of-phenol/31548#31548**

Comment: Completely a duplicate of **https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72184/friedel-crafts-reaction-of-anisole#autocomment382586**

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72184/friedel-crafts-reaction-of-anisole#autocomment382587

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Friedel-Crafts acylation of anisole with acetyl chloride and aluminium chloride as catalyst is a standard laboratory procedure to synthesize [acetanisole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetanisole).

[image: source: Wikipedia, user Jü]

The fact that this reaction is possible does not imply that there is no complex formation with $\ce{AlCl3}$. On the contrary, it is quite probable that such complexes do form due to the interaction of the methoxy oxygen with $\ce{AlCl3}$.

Therefore, and to compensate the formation of complexes with the resulting ketone, $\ce{AlCl3}$ is added in more than two-fold excess in the above synthesis.

Comment: if complex is formed then does that mean friedel crafts in anisole forms meta product?